# I have 2 columns A & B i need compare B column data with A irrespective of all rows

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have 2 columns A & B i need compare B column data with A irrespective of all rows if it is matched then output should be like below

```
  A .     B .     C 
Deepak  Deepak  Deepak 
Kiran   Venky   
Arun    heloo   Heloo
Varun   Lekha   
Manju   Deepak  Deepak Deepak
heloo   sambha  
Deepak  subbu   
        love    
        sudip   
        jyothi  
        kiran
```

In the above example String Deepak matched with A row hence it is displayed in C column 2 nd row no matched found so blank 3rd row string "heloo" matched hence displayed 4th row blank 5th row string "Deepak deepak" should display because in column there is duplication.

Can anyone help on this. I tried Index and it didnt work.

Comment: How about using `=COUNTIF(A:A,B:B)` to get the amount of how often B is found in A? Or `=REPT(B:B,COUNTIF(A:A,B:B))` to get the words like in column C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following formulas:

- Column D:
  `=COUNTIF(A:A,B:B)` or  `=COUNTIF(A:A,B2)`
- Column E:
  `=COUNTIF(B:B,B:B)` or  `=COUNTIF(B:B,B2)`
- Column F:
  `=COUNTIF(B$B1:B2,B:B)` or  `=COUNTIF(B$B1:B2,B2)`
- Column G:
  `=IF(D:D>0,TRIM(REPT(B:B & " ",F:F)),"")` or  `=IF(D2>0,TRIM(REPT(B2 & " ",F2)),"")`

[image]

Comment: This worked exactly how it was explained above, thanks a ton . Only change which is did is : Column F:=COUNTIF($B$1:B2,B:B) rest of the code seems flawless.

Comment: Thanks @Pᴇʜ it was really helpful and also easy to understand. Sub heading of the column is perfect which made me to grab things faster.

Comment: is it possible to print  the string value in the next line in the same row like . Deepak 
Deepak 
Deepak like how we will use in c "\n"

Comment: Substitute the space with `CHAR(10)` after `TRIM` like `=IF(D2>0,SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(REPT(B2 & " ",F2))," ",CHAR(10)),"")` and activate "Wrap Text" in the ribbon for these cells. Also see [Add a line break with a formula](https://exceljet.net/formula/add-a-line-break-with-a-formula)